# PHP to C# variables

Tags: c#, php

I have the following PHPcode:

```
include 'db.php';
$user = $_POST['username'];
$q = $connection->query('SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE username=".$user."');
foreach($q AS $row) {
echo $row['id'];
}
```

I'm trying to make a C# application post a variable to a PHP page that then queries the db and echos a string that will be used in the C# app. My C# code looks like this:

```
public string getId(string url)
    {
        string test = "testing123"; 
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["username"] = test;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] resp = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", formData);
            string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp);
            wc.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
            return responsefromserver;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I just want to write what the app gets back from the PHP page to the console and then return it, but when I run the app, it returns nothing. At least it appears to. Does anyone have any idea why? Sorry if this is blatantly obvious, I'm still pretty new to the whole C# thing.

Comment: You are in single quotes so `username=".$user."` is incorrect. You also are open to SQL injections. Should be `username="' . $user. '"`... or invert the quote usage and get rid of the `.`s.

Comment: Ohhhh.... I knew it had to be something like that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Note the SQL injection issue as well. Should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$q = $connection->query('SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE username=".$user."');
```

with

```
$q = $connection->query('SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE username='.$user.';');
```

and try again.

As a best practise, use prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.